# generate duplicate rows in Select statement in Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a select statement with more than 10 columns.I have to repeat the rows wherever the data is missing based on the date.
The rows which are to be generated should have data from the preceding rows sorted by date ascending.
The date range to be considered is based on grouping of id.

The date is actually a range from 15th March to 16th April,but for sample I have taken only limited rows.

For example the data is as shown below.

```
    ID  Date    Type    Code  Location
   ==== ======  ===     ====   ====
    1   15-Mar  TG       RET    X1
    1   17-Mar  GG       CAN    S2
    1   20-Mar  DTR      ISS    D2
    2   14-Apr  YT       RR     F2
    2   16-Apr  F        FC     F1
```

*Excepted output:*

```
    ID  Date    Type    Code  Location
    === ====    ====   ====  ======  
    1   15-Mar  TG      RET    X1
    *1  16-Mar  TG      RET    X1*
    1   17-Mar  GG      CAN    S2
    *1  18-Mar  GG      CAN    S2*
    *1  19-Mar  GG      CAN    S2*
    1   20-Mar  DTR     ISS    D2
    2   14-Apr  YT      RR     F2
    *2  15-Apr  YT      RR     F2*
    2   16-Apr  F       FC     F1
```

Comment: Why is there still a gap between `20-Mar` and `14-Apr`? For simplicity or is there another rule?

Comment: @lukas-eder Sorry, I will edit the question, grouping is on id

Comment: Aha, so you want to fill gaps only between the min and max dates per ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a working example of a possible way to achieve your desired output. I'm utilizing Oracle's `LAST_VALUE` analytic function with the `IGNORE NULLS` option and `ORDER BY` clause.

Test data:

```
CREATE TABLE so123 (
  id NUMBER,
  d DATE,
  type VARCHAR2(10),
  code VARCHAR2(10),
  location VARCHAR2(10)
);

INSERT INTO so123 VALUES (1, DATE '2015-05-15', 'TG', 'RET', 'X1');
INSERT INTO so123 VALUES (1, DATE '2015-05-17', 'GG', 'CAN', 'S2');
INSERT INTO so123 VALUES (1, DATE '2015-05-20', 'DTR', 'ISS', 'D2');
INSERT INTO so123 VALUES (2, DATE '2015-04-14', 'YT', 'RR', 'F2');
INSERT INTO so123 VALUES (2, DATE '2015-04-16', 'F', 'FC', 'F1');

COMMIT;
```

The select itself:

```
WITH
  dmm AS (
    SELECT MIN(d) min_d, MAX(d) max_d FROM so123
  )
SELECT
    NVL(s.id, LAST_VALUE(s.id) IGNORE NULLS OVER (ORDER BY dt.d)) AS id,
    dt.d,
    NVL(s.type, LAST_VALUE(s.type) IGNORE NULLS OVER (ORDER BY dt.d)) AS type,
    NVL(s.code, LAST_VALUE(s.code) IGNORE NULLS OVER (ORDER BY dt.d)) AS code,
    NVL(s.location, LAST_VALUE(s.location) IGNORE NULLS OVER (ORDER BY dt.d)) AS location
  FROM (
    SELECT min_d + level - 1 as d
      FROM dmm
    CONNECT BY min_d + level - 1 <= max_d
  ) dt LEFT JOIN so123 s ON (dt.d = s.d)
ORDER BY dt.d
;
```

Output:

```
        ID D                TYPE       CODE       LOCATION 
---------- ---------------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         2 14-04-2015 00:00 YT         RR         F2         
         2 15-04-2015 00:00 YT         RR         F2         
         2 16-04-2015 00:00 F          FC         F1         
         2 17-04-2015 00:00 F          FC         F1         
         2 18-04-2015 00:00 F          FC         F1         
         2 19-04-2015 00:00 F          FC         F1         
         2 20-04-2015 00:00 F          FC         F1         
         2 21-04-2015 00:00 F          FC         F1         
         2 22-04-2015 00:00 F          FC         F1         
         2 23-04-2015 00:00 F          FC         F1         
         2 24-04-2015 00:00 F          FC         F1         
         2 25-04-2015 00:00 F          FC         F1         
         2 26-04-2015 00:00 F          FC         F1         
         2 27-04-2015 00:00 F          FC         F1         
         2 28-04-2015 00:00 F          FC         F1         
         2 29-04-2015 00:00 F          FC         F1         
         2 30-04-2015 00:00 F          FC         F1         
         2 01-05-2015 00:00 F          FC         F1         
         2 02-05-2015 00:00 F          FC         F1         
         2 03-05-2015 00:00 F          FC         F1         
         2 04-05-2015 00:00 F          FC         F1         
         2 05-05-2015 00:00 F          FC         F1         
         2 06-05-2015 00:00 F          FC         F1         
         2 07-05-2015 00:00 F          FC         F1         
         2 08-05-2015 00:00 F          FC         F1         
         2 09-05-2015 00:00 F          FC         F1         
         2 10-05-2015 00:00 F          FC         F1         
         2 11-05-2015 00:00 F          FC         F1         
         2 12-05-2015 00:00 F          FC         F1         
         2 13-05-2015 00:00 F          FC         F1         
         2 14-05-2015 00:00 F          FC         F1         
         1 15-05-2015 00:00 TG         RET        X1         
         1 16-05-2015 00:00 TG         RET        X1         
         1 17-05-2015 00:00 GG         CAN        S2         
         1 18-05-2015 00:00 GG         CAN        S2         
         1 19-05-2015 00:00 GG         CAN        S2         
         1 20-05-2015 00:00 DTR        ISS        D2         

 37 rows selected
```

How does that work? We generate all the dates between the MIN and MAX dates from the source table. To do that, we use the `CONNECT BY` clause to make Oracle generate records until the condition `min_d + level - 1 <= max_d` doesn't hold any longer.

Then, we take the generated records and `LEFT JOIN` the source table to them. Here comes the `LAST_VALUE` analytic function's magic into play. This function searches for the last non-null (the `IGNORE NULLS` option) value in the table, using specified ordering and fills in the missing fields.

You can read more about that function here:

http://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/first-value-and-last-value-analytic-functions.php

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/18fa9/1)

Comment: you are just awesome!! Thanks you so much for  your effort and explanation.You went out of the way to help me.Great!Really appreciate your expertise!

Comment: Hmm, but this solution doesn't partition by ID, or did I get the assignment wrong? This seems to produce too many records...

Comment: @LukasEder Check the test data provided by RajA - ID is not unique. The number of records is correct - all dates between MIN and MAX, none of the dates is used more than once. Partitioning could be added of course, I've just provided an example.

Comment: I asked the OP in the comments: *"Aha, so you want to fill gaps only between the min and max dates per ID?"* which they replied to with *"Yes"*. The expected output from the question doesn't match yours, I think partitioning is really needed - although the OP accepted, so perhaps this is good enough :) Still, would be interested to see a partitioned version to match the question's expected data.

Comment: @Lukas Actually to be honest, Lukas is right, but I appreciate  Sir Przemyslaw Kruglej efforts too.. I can modify now according to my need from his query .I knew model clause could insert rows ,but I was not confident of using it as I don't have much grasp on it.But I really want to learn MODEL clause.At the End I really thank both of the experts, I would be definitely looking to learn more from you guys.

Comment: You just need to adjust the grouping in the select in the `WITH` clause, add partitioning to the analytic function and ID column to the `JOIN`. I'll update my answer later tonight.

Comment: @PrzemyslawKruglej  I am getting an error ORA-30484: missing window specification for this function even though I copied the exact syntax, On contrary when I remove IGNORE NULLS the error does not come but the result is not as expected. I am on version 11g R1

Comment: @przemyslaw  I had a different database which is having11gR2 and I just tried a simple query with last_value "Ignore Nulls" option and it works.So it's not working in Release 1 :-(

Comment: I wasn't aware that `LAST_VALUE` with those options wasn't available in 11gR1, I guess you could try the select from the other answer and change the acceptance of my answer.

Comment: @przemyslaw-kruglej  Well I created dblink from 11gR2 to 11gR1 and its working fine now..Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Fear not, you must, when exposed to a problem that can be solved optimally using Oracle's `MODEL` clause. The following query will return the wanted result:

#### Solution:

```sql
SELECT id, d, type, code, location
FROM (
  SELECT 
    id, d, type, code, location, 
    null min_d,
    null max_d
  FROM t
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    id, null, null, null, null,
    MIN(d),
    MAX(d)
  FROM t
  GROUP BY id
)
MODEL RETURN UPDATED ROWS
  PARTITION BY (id)
  DIMENSION BY (d)
  MEASURES (type, code, location, min_d, max_d)
  RULES (
    type    [FOR d FROM min_d[null] TO max_d[null] INCREMENT INTERVAL '1' DAY] = 
             NVL(type[cv(d)], type[cv(d) - 1]),
    code    [FOR d FROM min_d[null] TO max_d[null] INCREMENT INTERVAL '1' DAY] = 
             NVL(code[cv(d)], code[cv(d) - 1]),
    location[FOR d FROM min_d[null] TO max_d[null] INCREMENT INTERVAL '1' DAY] = 
             NVL(location[cv(d)], location[cv(d) - 1])
  )
ORDER BY id, d
```

<sub>[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b1a92/2)</sub>

#### Result:

```
| ID |                       D | TYPE | CODE | LOCATION |
|----|-------------------------|------|------|----------|
|  1 | March, 15 2015 00:00:00 |   TG |  RET |       X1 |
|  1 | March, 16 2015 00:00:00 |   TG |  RET |       X1 |
|  1 | March, 17 2015 00:00:00 |   GG |  CAN |       S2 |
|  1 | March, 18 2015 00:00:00 |   GG |  CAN |       S2 |
|  1 | March, 19 2015 00:00:00 |   GG |  CAN |       S2 |
|  1 | March, 20 2015 00:00:00 |  DTR |  ISS |       D2 |
|  2 | April, 14 2015 00:00:00 |   YT |   RR |       F2 |
|  2 | April, 15 2015 00:00:00 |   YT |   RR |       F2 |
|  2 | April, 16 2015 00:00:00 |    F |   FC |       F1 |
```

#### Explanation:

Think of `MODEL` as a SQL spreadsheet language, kind of like Microsoft Excel, but much more powerful - because SQL!

```
SELECT id, d, type, code, location
FROM (

  -- This is your original data, plus two columns
  SELECT 
    id, d, type, code, location, 
    null min_d,
    null max_d
  FROM t
  UNION ALL

  -- This is a utility record containing the MIN(d) and MAX(d) values for
  -- each ID partition. We'll use these MIN / MAX values to generate rows
  SELECT
    id, null, null, null, null,
    MIN(d),
    MAX(d)
  FROM t
  GROUP BY id
)

-- We're using the RETURN UPDATED ROWS clause, as we don't want the utility
-- record from above in the results
MODEL RETURN UPDATED ROWS

  -- Your requirement is to fill gaps between dates within each id PARTITION
  PARTITION BY (id)

  -- The dates are your DIMENSION, i.e. the axis along which we're generating rows
  DIMENSION BY (d)

  -- The remaining rows are the MEASURES, i.e. the calculated values in each "cell"
  MEASURES (type, code, location, min_d, max_d)

  -- The following RULES are used to generate rows. For each MEASURE, we simply
  -- iterate from the MIN(d) to the MAX(d) value, referencing the min_d / max_d
  -- values from the utility record above
  RULES (
    type    [FOR d FROM min_d[null] TO max_d[null] INCREMENT INTERVAL '1' DAY] = 
             NVL(type[cv(d)], type[cv(d) - 1]),
    code    [FOR d FROM min_d[null] TO max_d[null] INCREMENT INTERVAL '1' DAY] = 
             NVL(code[cv(d)], code[cv(d) - 1]),
    location[FOR d FROM min_d[null] TO max_d[null] INCREMENT INTERVAL '1' DAY] = 
             NVL(location[cv(d)], location[cv(d) - 1])
  )
ORDER BY id, d
```

Comment: you are great! I wanted to learn Model clause.Is there any site where it's explained in detail with lots of examples. By the way the explanation you gave helped me lot to understand the Model Clause query.Thanks once again Lukas!

Comment: I just didn't want  Przemyslaw to bother again and tell him that I needed a partition on id as what you mentioned in the comments above.I just that I would try to figure that out :-) Thanks Sir

Comment: I usually have to dig up `MODEL` syntax myself. It's a bit of a challenge :) I then like to refer to the official whitepaper by Oracle: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/bi-foundation/10gr1-twp-bi-dw-sqlmodel-131067.pdf